# Drupal module implementation guidance

Tags: drupal, drupal-7, drupal-modules

I'm very new to Drupal development and I would really appreciate a little guidance with a piece of work I need to create.

Essentially my client has asked for a a site to be made out of 'modules' (their term - I'm not sure if they understand what Drupal modules are). Each of these 'modules' has a number of configurable fields that has to be set on a per-content page basis.

So, for example, a 'module' may have the following fields to configure "turn title on/off", "change title colour", "change title". This 'module' can only be used once per content page but may be used across multiple content pages with different values for the fields.

Now the only example I've seen that comes close is the 'Annotate' module from the Pro Drupal Development book but I'm wondering if there's a better way of meeting the requirements.

Answer (score 0):

If I understood you well what you actually need is a new content type (or few of them). So, when you create one, beside default fields Drupal give you (title and body) you should create other ones you need - i.e. "turn title on/off" checkbox, color (you can install additional modules that will give you i.e. color picker field type) and so on.

After that you can create new pages (nodes) in that content type and for every one of the page you can set different values for those fields.